# cin.get() skips when i use getline() with delimiter

Tags: c++, cin

i am trying to get this very simple program working . program runs  it print out 'Please, enter your full name: ' . i enter my name with space 'john johnny'(ignore ''for reference only) then i enter delimiter $ and press enter key . program was supposed to stop at cin.get(); so that i can read the output but program the closes . help me out i am very newb in it

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;

void main ()
{
  string name;

  cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
  getline (cin,name,'$');
  cout << "Hello, " << name ;

  cin.get();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new line character, that was entered by the user after the `$`, will remain in the input stream as it will not have been consumed by `getline()`: this is the character that `get()` reads.

Just use `getline`, using new line as delimiter (the default).

Comment: @AliAsif, when u pressed the enter key a new line will have been inserted into standard input.

Comment: thanks for the reply . understood the problem you described . can you post the solution as code ?

Comment: i am using delimiter to get multiple line input from user too in single string . for example address of user . for address user press enter key and moves to next line if i use delimiter .

Comment: i used cin.ignore('$');  before cin.get();  , working for now  .